# GOPATH value setting

Tags: windows, go

I'm install the go with the go1.3.1.windows-amd64.msi, after installation  GOROOT is default setting, I found the 
D:\Programs\Go\bin in the PATH,then I create a GOPATH environment variant,
when using the 'go get' command, error occurs:

package github.com/coreos/etcd: cannot download, $GOPATH must not be set to $GOROOT. For more details see: go help gopath

OS: windows 7

GOPATH will conflict with GOROOT?

How can I set these two PATH values?

Answer (score 32):

- `GOROOT` must reference the folder where you installed GO
- `GOPATH` must reference an empty folder which will be your **[workspace](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces)** (src/pkg/bin for your projects)

Add those two variables in your user environment variables.

A `go get github.com/coreos/etcd` should:

- download the sources in `%GOPATH%/src/github.com/coreos/etcd` (`src` is created for you)
- compile it in `%GOPATH%/pkg/windows_amd64` (`pkg/` is created for you, `windows_amd64` reflects your windows architecture)
- with `go install`, install it in `%GOPATH%/bin` (`bin/` is also created for you)

Note: with Go 1.8+ (Q2 2017), `GOPATH` might be set for you by default to (on Windows) `%USERPROFILE%/go`.
On Linux, it would be **`$HOME/go`**: see [issue 17262](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17262).

---

Update 2018, three years later: `GOPATH` is becoming obsolete with **[Go 1.11 modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules)**:

```
mkdir newProject
cd newProject
set GO111MODULE=on
go mod init myproject
```

Comment: As he said, point your GOPATH to a separate folder from your GOROOT. A useful vendoring technique is to keep a standard workspace when you are fooling around and then create a separate workspace per project you want to keep exact dependencies of. Alternatively, use [godep](https://github.com/tools/godep).

Answer (score 5):

I faced with the same problem. However i set everything as it was said in the tutorial  but forgot to restart `cmd`. So the steps were:

1. Download and install `Go` distribution(the `GOROOT` variable was set automatically)
2. Create new folder wherever you like for your workspace, create there 3 directories: `bin`, `src` and `pkg`
3. Then go to **Control Panel** `->` **All Control Panel Items** `->` **System** `->` **Advansed System Settings** `->` tab **Advanced** `->` **Environment Variables** `->` add new system variable by clicking **New** on **System varaibles** `->` Variable name = `GOPATH`, Variable value = `Your:\directory\that\you\created`
4. When you're done, **RESTART** your `cmd` or `Bash`(**that's important**) and you have your `GOPATH` set. To be sure run `go env` and you will see your value.

Answer (score 1):

You should not set `$GOROOT`.

Type `export GOROOT=""` to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just `set GOPATH=[path]`  would do your work.

Comment: Didn't make any change