# Golang 1.5 vendors - Cannot find package

Tags: go

Trying to build my project in go lang using version 1.5 with `GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT="1"` turned on to ensure I look for the vendors locally.

My structure is:

```
apps_api
   main.go
   build.sh
   src
      controllers
      models
      views
   vendor
      github.com
      golang.org
      .....
```

build.sh contains

```
export GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT="1"
export GOPATH=`pwd`
go build .
```

controller file example

```
import (
    "models"
    "views"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)
```

But i get lots of errors saying package not found see below for exmaple

```
src/controllers/app-versions.go:10:2: cannot find package "github.com/asaskevich/govalidator" in any of:
    /Users/ereeve/.gvm/gos/go1.5/src/github.com/asaskevich/govalidator (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/ereeve/Documents/gocode/src/apps_api/src/github.com/asaskevich/govalidator (from $GOPATH)

src/controllers/index.go:4:2: cannot find package "github.com/chnlr/baseurl" in any of:
    /Users/ereeve/.gvm/gos/go1.5/src/github.com/chnlr/baseurl (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/ereeve/Documents/gocode/src/apps_api/src/github.com/chnlr/baseurl (from $GOPATH)
```

If i add these lines into my build.sh file it will build, but I don't want to use go get because I am using go 1.5 with the vendors locally inside my project to avoid dependancies.

```
# go get github.com/gin-gonic/gin
# go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
# go get github.com/rif/cache2go
....
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: have you try go get github.com/asaskevich/govalidator ?

Comment: I am using go 1.5 so I have that file inside vendor/github.com to avoid using go get then having different versions on different environments

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IIRC, `GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT` will work only if the package you're building is inside `$GOPATH/src`, so setting

```
export GOPATH=`pwd`
```

in your `build.sh` makes it fail. If you put your `apps_api` inside say `~/fakegopath/src/` and run

```
env GOPATH="${HOME}/fakegopath/src/" GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT="1" go build .
```

it should work.

Comment: Thanks but I am getting this: go: GOPATH entry cannot start with shell metacharacter '~': "~/Documents/gocode/src/" - do i need to explicitly fill out the GOPATH?

Comment: Try replacing `~` with `${HOME}`.

Comment: I now get ($GOPATH not set)?

Comment: export GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT="1"
export GOPATH="$HOME/Documents/gocode"
go build . - tried {HOME} too

Comment: Are both exports on the same line? In that case either add a semicolon after every export statement (`export A=a; export B=b; echo $A $B`) or just use `env` like in my answer.

Comment: Ok so the semicolons seems to have fixed the issue, now i get this:

main.go:4:2: cannot find package "controllers" in any of:
 /Users/ereeve/Documents/gocode/src/apps_api/vendor/controllers (vendor tree)
 /Users/ereeve/.gvm/gos/go1.5/src/controllers (from $GOROOT)
 /Users/ereeve/Documents/gocode/src/controllers (from $GOPATH)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91832/discussion-between-elliot-reeve-and-ainar-g).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25499670/gopath-value-setting
GOPATH is the path to an empty folder for building your code

Comment: IMO this answer is dangerously hack-y